# C++ combine function calls like C# expressions

Tags: lambda, expression-trees, c++-amp

What I am basically trying to do is take a string that represents a mathematical function such as

```
"4x^2+3"
```

and parse it into a function my application can invoke later. In C# I know that I can do this using the [Expression Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx). Once its parsed I can combine the parsed pieces without having multiple if checks or switch statements in my code.

Is there some similar way to do this in C++. I would like to parse the string once and when I plug in parameters later it will not have to parse the tree again or follow a secondary description of the function to follow.

Also bonus points if the solution can work using [C++ Amp library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265136.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703082/parsing-math-expression-in-c-c]. If you're simply looking for a library, try googling for math expression parser c++

Comment: Not looking for a library, looking at how to create expressions the same way in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. The Expression library equivalent is [Boost.Proto](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/proto.html)