# Stringstream math operations

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

Lets say I have a string stream that contains the string `1+2`. Now if I get the int value of this string stream, I get `1` as the result. Is there a way to get the expected result of `3`?

Comment: Why should the expected output be 3? This is a scanning & parsing problem

Comment: @RoQuOTriX well I have written 1+2, so it would be nice, if there is a way to automatically calculate this...

Comment: Will it always be the case that you have `ABC+XYZ`?

Comment: Yes you have a string containing three chars "1+2". A string isn't a calculation term. I guess, if you search for "parsing math strings" you will find something

Comment: @scohe001 what do you mean?

Comment: reinterpretation of data is not purpose of stringstream. you put string in stringstream, you get the same string back, to interpret this string is not part of stringstream responsibility. Analogy: you put iron bars into safe, and asking why i cant get sword from the safe ?

Comment: I mean is it guaranteed that when you go to read from the string stream, it'll always be `some_number+some_other_number`? Or are you trying to handle *any* mathematical expression?

Comment: @scohe001 it won't be just addition, it will be all basic mathematical expressions

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736745/which-data-structure-used-to-solve-a-simple-math-equation

Comment: @RoQuOTriX this has nothing to do with my question, this is only something that I could use if I have to implement that on my own...

Comment: You asked "Is there a way to get the expected result of 3?" I gave you a way to get the expected output, so why has this nothing to do with the question?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I asked for string streams...

Comment: @user11914177 Irrelevant: the fundamental problem, and its solutions, are the same. Unless your specific problem is the conversion between strings and stringstreams, in which case that’s what your question should focus on, rather on the interpretation of mathematical expressions.

Comment: You even can use a punch card to represent "1+2". Problem stays the same

Comment: @KonradRudolph @RoQuOTriX Yes, the fundamental problem is the same, but I haven't asked for a general algorithm, I asked for a **specific** solution for `std::stringstream`, **not for a general algorithm**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could make your own `result` type and then have a custom extraction operator that reads from the string stream the way you want it to:

```
struct result {
    double val;
    bool err;
    std::string err_val;
};

std::istringstream& operator>>(std::istringstream &iss, result &r) {
    double lhs, rhs;
    char op;
    //Should probably add some check to make sure this read happens okay...
    iss >> lhs >> op >> rhs; 

    if (op == '+') {
        r.val = lhs + rhs;
        r.err = false;
    } else {
        r.err = true;
        r.err_val = "I can only handle addition!";
    }
    return iss;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss("1+2");
    result res;
    iss >> res;

    std::cout << "Result is: " << res.val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See it run here: https://ideone.com/LKAlag

Answer (score 2):

Not using the standard C++ library.  Expression parsing is not part of standard C++.  You will have to write your own.